# Oracle Trim trailing whitespace

Tags: sql, oracle, character-trimming

```
SELECT user_id
FROM
USER_DUMPS
WHERE USER_ID like 'AB%'
```

I need to trim the whitespace from the right side of the USER_DUMPS table results. Results have 3 whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM user_id) AS user_id
FROM USER_DUMPS 
WHERE USER_ID like 'AB%'
```

Comment: What if it is not just spaces but other whitespace characters?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Assuming that there are other characters(tab) they could be defined to be removed: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6f94c49671cf54ce911cf73d88b7359b)

Answer (score 2):

You might use

[`RTRIM`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php)

( *no need to use any argument, since the `RTRIM(string)` function removes all trailing spaces from string if no argument specified.* ) :

```
SELECT RTRIM(user_id) as "Trimmed Text"
FROM
USER_DUMPS
WHERE USER_ID like 'AB%';
```